# Cakephp naming convention for table

Tags: cakephp, naming-conventions, cakephp-2.x

I am new to CakePHP and building my first web project for customer service request.
I have following tables in database...

- customers
- customer_addresses
- customer_service_requests
- service_requests

service_requests table has foreign keys:

- customer_id
- customer_address_id

While baking MVC for service request, I'm getting following errors

> Error: Table customers_addresses for model CustomerAddress was not found  in datasource default.

The ServiceRequest model has a belongsTo relation as

```
'CustomerAddress' => arrray(
  'className' => 'CustomerAddress',
  'foreignKey' => 'customer_address_id',
  'conditions' => ' ',
  'fields' => ' ',
  'order' => ' '
 )
```

cakephp version : 2.7.8

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version - thanks! The table names look correct. I'd kinda doubt that the error originates from the shown association, as this should look for a table named `customer_addresses`, see  **http://inflector.cakephp.org/CustomerAddress** (tableize). If bake looks for `customers_addresses`, then you may be using a buggy CakePHP version, or you have a typo somewhere, or a constellation of names that are causing bake to look for a `hasAndBelongsToMany` join table for `customers` and `addresses` (even though that should be reversed in that case), or...

Comment: i have already checked for inflector and the result for tableized is customer_addresses. I'm using cakephp v 2.7.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like according to the convention, they are expecting the databse table name to be customers_addresses for the model CustomerAddress .

You have two options.

1. Either modify your database table name to customers_addresses.
2. Create a model CustomerAddress.php and write the following line within your model.

   ```
   class CustomerAddress extends AppModel{

       public $useTable = "customers_addresses";
   }
   ```

Peace! xD

Comment: renaming customer_addresses to customers_addresses then I'll have to change foreign key accordingly to customers_address_id ? Are the naming-convention I'm using is wrong ?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to change your foreign key. You could specify it in the join array instead, like you have done above. Example, "foreignKey" => "customer_address_id "